# Understanding the need to refer to text by ID

Tags: android

I am using the Big Nerd Ranch Guide to learn Android. I have to set the text in a TextView/Box using the code below -

```
//Get an int id for the question.
int question = model.getQuestionId();

//This id is found in the R file
private TextView mQuestionTextView;

//some more code here
mQuestionTextView.setText(question);
```

Here, the author passed the ID of the question which is actually "mapped" to the strings.XML file. Instead, I want to just pick up that string and then set it in mQuestionTextView ? How do I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get a string from the resource file based on its ID, you can use:

```
String mystring = getResources().getString(question);
```